# How to add header names to the first column

Tags: r

I have 2 txt file. first one have data and other one have variable name.
I loaded data into R and Now I want add column names to the data frame  which specified in `variable_names.txt` file. How can I do that.

My steps :

```
mydata <- read.table("wine.txt")  # Read data
mydata

structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V2 = c(14.23, 13.2, 13.16, 14.37, 13.24, 14.2, 
14.39, 14.06, 14.83, 13.86, 14.1, 14.12, 13.75, 14.75), V3 = c(1.71, 
1.78, 2.36, 1.95, 2.59, 1.76, 1.87, 2.15, 1.64, 1.35, 2.16, 1.48, 
1.73, 1.73), V4 = c(2.43, 2.14, 2.67, 2.5, 2.87, 2.45, 2.45, 
2.61, 2.17, 2.27, 2.3, 2.32, 2.41, 2.39), V5 = c(15.6, 11.2, 
18.6, 16.8, 21, 15.2, 14.6, 17.6, 14, 16, 18, 16.8, 16, 11.4), 
V6 = c(127L, 100L, 101L, 113L, 118L, 112L, 96L, 121L, 97L, 
98L, 105L, 95L, 89L, 91L), V7 = c(2.8, 2.65, 2.8, 3.85, 2.8, 
3.27, 2.5, 2.6, 2.8, 2.98, 2.95, 2.2, 2.6, 3.1), V8 = c(3.06, 
2.76, 3.24, 3.49, 2.69, 3.39, 2.52, 2.51, 2.98, 3.15, 3.32, 
2.43, 2.76, 3.69), V9 = c(0.28, 0.26, 0.3, 0.24, 0.39, 0.34, 
0.3, 0.31, 0.29, 0.22, 0.22, 0.26, 0.29, 0.43), V10 = c(2.29, 
1.28, 2.81, 2.18, 1.82, 1.97, 1.98, 1.25, 1.98, 1.85, 2.38, 
1.57, 1.81, 2.81), V11 = c(5.64, 4.38, 5.68, 7.8, 4.32, 6.75, 
5.25, 5.05, 5.2, 7.22, 5.75, 5, 5.6, 5.4), V12 = c(1.04, 
1.05, 1.03, 0.86, 1.04, 1.05, 1.02, 1.06, 1.08, 1.01, 1.25, 
1.17, 1.15, 1.25), V13 = c(3.92, 3.4, 3.17, 3.45, 2.93, 2.85, 
3.58, 3.58, 2.85, 3.55, 3.17, 2.82, 2.9, 2.73), V14 = c(1065, 
1050, 1185, 1480, 735, 1450, 1290, 1295, 1045, 1045, 1510, 
1280, 1320, 1150)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Now I want put header name with respect to each column.

```
mydata <- data.frame(Class label,Alcohol,Malic acid,Ash,Alcalinity of ash,Magnesium,Total phenols,Flavanoids,Nonflavanoid phenols,Proanthocyanins,Color intensity,Hue,Diluted wines,Proline)
```

Comment: try: `colnames(mydata) <- c("Class label","Alcohol","Malic acid","Ash","Alcalinity of ash","Magnesium","Total phenols","Flavanoids","Nonflavanoid phenols","Proanthocyanins","Color intensity","Hue","Diluted wines","Proline")` or `colnames(mydata) <- var_names_object`

Comment: But I am getting below error message::Error in names(mydata) <- variable_names : 
  'names' attribute [14] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. The Easiest one: when you are reading the data using `read.table`, you can specify the column names through the `col.names` argument of the function with appropriate vector. The function provides other options that you can access by typing `help(read.table)` or `?read.table`
2. After having read the data you can use `colnames(your_data_frame)` and set it to a vector of names of your choice. In your case:

   `colnames(mydata)<-c("Class label","Alcohol","Malic acid","Ash",...)`

Comment: Thank u so much for help. It's solved.

Comment: @Kumar P please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

As per @hssay's answer, except to add that you should avoid using spaces in your column names. Here's an example with the kind of vector syntax you'd need, and a suggestion as to how to format your column names:

```
names(mydata) <- c("ClassLabel","Alcohol","MalicAcid","Ash",
    "AlcalinityOfAsh","Magnesium","TotalPhenols","Flavanoids",
    "NonflavanoidPhenols","Proanthocyanins","ColorIntensity",
    "Hue","DilutedWines","Proline")
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all the your variable names to a vector and then apply names function to your data

```
    variable_names <- c("Class label","Alcohol","Malic acid","Ash","Alcalinity of ash","Magnesium","Total phenols","Flavanoids",
      "Nonflavanoid phenols","Proanthocyanins","Color intensity","Hue","Diluted wines","Proline")

       names(mydata) <- variable_names
```

Or you can just add column names of of data frame which have values by

```
colnames(mydata) <-colnames(no_data)
```

Comment: @kumar P Need to check the column names have same length in both the data frames

Comment: Error in names(mydata) <- variable_names : 
  'names' attribute [14] must be the same length as the vector [1]